# Connecting view models to a model and its changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am developing a simple video player application using Prism 6. I am more familiar with the MVC approach and have a question regarding cross-view communication. Here is how my application is currently designed:

Views:

- ControlView - Contains buttons to play, pause, fast forward, rewind, and stop.
- VideoView - The actual view for the video frames.
- MenuView - Defines the top menu bar with two functions: load file, exit program.
- InfoView - Shows statistics about the video such as # frames, length in time, file path, etc.

Each of these views has an associated ViewModel with no functionality as of now.

Model:

- VideoFile - Contains meta information about the video file that is ready for playback.

My first task is to load a video. Within `MenuView` I am able to use `OpenFileDialog` to browse for a file. My goal is to somehow communicate with the other view models when a file has been loaded so they can perform the necessary actions (show the first frame, update the length of the video, etc.).

My first thought is to define a service which has a reference to the `VideoFile`:

```
public interface IVideoService {
    VideoFile PlayingVideoFile { get; set; }
}

public class VideoService : BindableBase, IVideoService {
    private VideoFile _playingVideoFile;

    public VideoFile PlayingVideoFile {
        get => _playingVideoFile;
        set => SetProperty(ref _playingVideoFile, value);
    }
}
```

I am just confusing myself. I am not sure how to implement this communication between the views. How can I implement communication of the model between all of the views in a way that agrees with Prism and MVVM principles?

Comment: Some communication options are explained [here](http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/09-Communication/). I tend to lean toward [Event Aggregation](http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/09-Communication/#event-aggregation).

Comment: All of the viewmodels (except the main viewmodel) should be children of some other viewmodel. They can expose events so that their parent viewmodel can arrange sibling-sibling communication via the events. Anything else is going to require a lot more time and effort for code that is much harder to write, understand, and maintain. Communication among viewmodels is absolutely trivial and easy. Any design that makes it hard is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks for the comment. Can you point me to any resources that would show me how Prism sets up child viewmodels? I am not sure how to link them together.

Comment: @orbv12 A child viewmodel is a property of the parent, like `public ChildViewModel MyChild { get; set; }` -- but it raises `PropertyChanged` in the setter of course. That's it. This is why these frameworks are such a terrible idea. They take incredibly simple things and make them mysterious and complicated. "Link them together". No. It's just a property.

Comment: Sometimes you have collections of child viewmodels as well. In that case, once again, the parent *creates* the child. It's right there. No mysterious Prism magic. Just regular programming. The buzzword for this IIRC is "viewmodel-centric design", which just means that the architecture of the application is a tree of viewmodels and child viewmodels, which can trivially communicate with each other. You display them in views via implicit datatemplates. Easy and very powerful.

Comment: That makes sense. I will apply that to the project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*How can I implement communication between all of the View[Model]s in a way that agrees with Prism and MVVM principles?*

I assume you are asking about communication between your ViewModels (there generally isn't a reason to have communication between your Views, hence the revision to your question).

There are two ways that I know of that leverage PRISM's codebase for ViewModel-ViewModel communication:

1) The `EventAggregator`

The `EventAggregator` uses a publisher-subscriber model for passing messages between ViewModels. While it can be used for communication with non-ViewModel components, it is generally advisable to limit its usage to *just* ViewModels.

2) `CompositeCommand`s

`CompositeCommand`s work by providing globally accessible "registration" points for commands in different ViewModels. *Assuming the `CompositeCommand` has been initialized (typically in some static constructor)*, you can simply register your ViewModel Commands with a given `CompositeCommand`. This will cause it to be executed every time the CompositeCommand is executed.

For the sake of brevity here, please refer to the existing documentation on both of these techniques for more information. They can be found at the site R. Richards alluded to in his comment (link: http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/09-Communication/)

Since you're trying to communicate with your other ViewModels when a new `VideoFile` is created/selected through `MenuView`, I would recommend the following:

1) Create a `CompositeCommand` called ProcessNewVideoFileSelectionCommand (or something to that effect).

2) Register any ViewModel-specific commands that need to respond to a new `VideoFile` with ProcessNewVideoFileSelectionCommand (e.g. InfoView's ViewModel will need to change its information to reflect the new `VideoFile`)

3) When a new `VideoFile` is selected in MenuView, execute ProcessNewVideoFileSelectionCommand. This will cause all `Command`s registered with it to execute (assuming that they can execute given the values returned by each of their respective `CanExecute(...)` methods).